# Issue with ng-repeat, blurjs, jquery and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

After solve this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226334/using-blur-js-with-angularjs) i'm trying to apply the solution in ng-repeat with something like this:

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item ng-repeat="element in list" href="#/app/playlists/{{element.id}}">
  <div id="bgToBlurContainer">
   <div blurred id="sourceblur" class="target">
    <div class="item-titlte-text">
     SOME TITLE
    </div>
    <div class="item-subtitlte-text">
     SOME SUBTITLE
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But this throw this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
 at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/Ejemplos/Ionic/primerionic/www/js/blur.js:196:58)
 at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:375:23)
 at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js:139:17)
 at $.fn.blurjs (http://localhost/Ejemplos/Ionic/primerionic/www/js/blur.js:193:15)
 at Object.compile (http://localhost/Ejemplos/Ionic/primerionic/www/js/app.js:27:14)
 at applyDirectivesToNode (http://localhost/Ejemplos/Ionic/primerionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14925:32)
 at compileNodes (http://localhost/Ejemplos/Ionic/primerionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14516:15)
 at compileNodes (http://localhost/Ejemplos/Ionic/primerionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14528:15)
 at compileNodes (http://localhost/Ejemplos/Ionic/primerionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14528:15)
 at compileNodes (http://localhost/Ejemplos/Ionic/primerionic/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14528:15) <div blurred="" id="sourceblur" class="target">
```

I'm using [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/), deleting the ng-repeat the blur works fine.

Some peoples on their blogs said that is a issue with compiler.

Any Suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I received this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

In my case it was due to having this chrome extension installed:
AngularJS Batarang

Once I disabled that chrome extension, the error went away.

(AngularJS Batarang has been very helpful in general. Unfortunately, it is causing me an error here.)

```
Mac: OSX 10.9.5
Chrome: Version 38.0.2125.111
Ionic: v1.0.0-beta.13
```